# How to write Angular2 npm module - Angular2 RC 6

Tags: angular, npm

I can't get my head around how to write a npm module for angular2.
Even though I found 2 tutorials ([One](https://medium.com/@OCombe/how-to-publish-a-library-for-angular-2-on-npm-5f48cdabf435#.kjtgsahnt), [Two](http://blog.angular-university.io/how-to-create-an-angular-2-library-and-how-to-consume-it-jspm-vs-webpack/)) there's none covering how to implement a angular2 module (`@NgModule`) as npm package.

What I don't understand, when exactly do I need to inject the module like the `BrowserModule` for example? Do I even have to inject it with my module or is it enough to just inject the directives?

My Plugin so far:
- https://github.com/yves-s/ng2-flexbox-grid/tree/develop
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-flexbox-grid

Currently it's a copy and update to RC6 of @btmorton's [angular2-grid](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-grid)

But I can't get it to work.

**UPDATE:**

This is the current state of my module [ng2-flexbox-grid.ts](https://github.com/yves-s/ng2-flexbox-grid/blob/develop/ng2-flexbox-grid.ts)

```
export * from './src/directives';
export * from './src/components';
export * from './src/interfaces';

import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {CommonModule} from '@angular/common';

import {NgGrid, NgGridItem}  from './src/directives';

const mapValuesToArray = (obj) => Object.keys(obj).map(key => obj[key]);
// const directives = mapValuesToArray(directiveItems);

export default {
    directives: [NgGrid, NgGridItem]
}

@NgModule({
    declarations: [],
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        CommonModule
    ],
    exports: [NgGrid, NgGridItem]
})
export class Ng2FlexboxGridModule {}
```

---

**UPDATE - Solution**

With the help of @Clint I could bring that baby home.

Probably the biggest problem was that I wasn't aware of how exactly `@NgModule` works. And I'm pretty sure it would have helped if I had carefully read the [`@NgModule` docs](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/ngmodule.html)

The important part though is to declare and export the modules directives. With that you just have to import the `FlexboxGridModule` to use it's exported directives.

**Export:**

```
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {NgGrid, NgGridItem} from './src/directives';

@NgModule({
    imports: [BrowserModule],
    declarations: [NgGrid, NgGridItem],
    exports: [NgGrid, NgGridItem]
})
export class FlexboxGridModule {}
```

**Import:**

```
import {NgModule}      from '@angular/core';
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser';

import {AppComponent}   from './app.component';
import {FlexboxGridModule} from "ng2-flexbox-grid";

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        FlexboxGridModule
    ],
    declarations: [AppComponent],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Comment: Question bodies are not the place for solutions. You can provide your solution as an answer and mark it as the best answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you make a module, you should be sure that it imports the modules and declares the components that it uses, as well as export anything that should be available to consumers. Ex:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [...modulesImConsuming],
  exports: [...modulesAndComponentsMyConsumersNeed],
  declarations: [...myModulesComponents]
})
```

In your instance, we would have (note the `declarations` change):

```
@NgModule({
    declarations: [NgGrid, NgGridItem],
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        CommonModule
    ],
    exports: [NgGrid, NgGridItem]
})
```

Then to consume our module, we just need to import it. When importing a module we get access to all components (`NgGrid`, `NgGridItem`) as well as any modules (and everything the exported module exports and so on) that are exported. In your case we would have:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [FlexboxGridModule]
})
```

Comment: I now added the directives to the declarations and exports section like:
```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        CommonModule
    ],
    declarations: [NgGrid, NgGridItem],
    exports: [NgGrid, NgGridItem]
})
```

But I still get the error: "Uncaught Unexpected value 'NgGrid' declared by the module 'AppModule'"

Comment: @Yves I misread your comment before, can you update your question and provide the code you are having issues with? Seems your github isn't up to date.

Comment: There is the problem, I don't know exactly where the issue is. The github repo on develop should be up to date. The root module is in ng2-flexbox-grid.ts but I'll update my question with the current state.

Comment: @Yves See my updated answer. Would you provide the AppModule you are using to consume the library as well?

Comment: Hey @Clint, it worked. Thanks for the quick explanation that was what I was missing. After I exported `NgGrid` and `NgGridItem` from my `@NgModule` and just imported the `FlexboxGridModule` I could start using the modules directives. I will update my question with the solution maybe it helps others. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

@NgModule and npm package serve a different purpose.
@NgModule is a facility for angular2 to encapsulate and load directives or filter dynamically.

Npm package is a facillity to package and distribute your code in an uniform way.
There is no relation whatsoever between the two (npm and NgModule).

I suggest you first write your NgModule without caring about Npm and test it in your application. Once it works ok. You can then add publish you module as a npm package.

Answer (score 0):

You should not import `BrowserModule` twice. You only should import this in the AppModule, as explained here: [Angular2 Docs](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/ngmodule-faq.html#!#q-browser-vs-common-module). I assume you do want your npm module to be able to lazy load.